# Set Validation Tooltip in CodeBehind instead of XAML

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, tooltip, code-behind

I would like to know how to translate the following code to codebehind instead of XAML:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
          Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The part I can't figure out is the Path portion. I have the following but it doesn't work:

```
new Trigger
{
    Property = Validation.HasErrorProperty,
    Value = true,
    Setters = 
    {
        new Setter
        {
            Property = Control.ToolTipProperty,
            // This part doesn't seem to work
            Value = new Binding("(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"){RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self}
         }
     }
 }
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out. It turns out that I was setting the trigger on the wrong property. I was trying to set it on the DataGridTextColumn CellStyle when I needed to apply it to the ElementStyle. Working code below:

```
new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = i + 1,
    Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].Value", i)) { ValidatesOnDataErrors = true, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged },
    ElementStyle = new Style
    {
        TargetType = typeof(TextBlock),
        Triggers =
        {        
            new Trigger
            {
                Property = Validation.HasErrorProperty,
                Value = true,
                Setters = 
                {
                    new Setter
                    {
                         Property = Control.ToolTipProperty,
                         Value = new Binding("(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"){RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }, ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx) (MSDN).

Comment: My issue isn't how to create bindings in code in general...its how I can do it in this particular case. I can't figure out how to bind to the Validation Errors. Specific help for this case would be appreciated.